# Firebase storage, downloading files without security token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

we have an app, that is used to collect sensitive information, that we turn into PDF files that we store in Firebase Storage.

The data in storage must be accessible from iOS, Android, Cloud Functions, Java Admin and Web.

As we have these files (in the end) hundreds of thousands, how can we be sure a malicious hacker is not scanning the storage urls to find out random tokens that work? Given time, they could get hold of considerable amount of data.

And Google has fantastic infrastructure to serve scanning at any scale :)

We can live with short lived tokens, but we can't afford to have forever and ever tokens.

Is there any advice or examples how to create

- one time token or
- short lived token or
- revoke token as a batch run
  from Cloud Functions

If none of the above is possible, we have to implement our own cloud functions that proxy the content to clients? (And be super duper extra careful that no client, function nor anything create the tokens..)

Comment: How would said hacker find the URLs?

Comment: They can infer much information from the apps to understand the general folder structure, after that it's brute forcing the token.

It may be more vise to attack users though, as the password is easier to crack (probably) and gives access to a lot more content.

Comment: I need to convince third parties that this is not a problem, so are there any resources I could use to do that? Like calculations how probable it is to guess the given token, or measures Google takes to stop password / token attacks?

Comment: For peace of mind, we'd really like to configure the token lifetime, we'd be more than happy to pay a premium to do so too. (Price xxx per 1000 revokes? Or something along those lines where token, that times out, would count as revoke.)

Comment: Isn't the token different on each download URL? I quickly checked a few of mine and they seemed to be.

Comment: Yes, but it still is security through obscurity, which I was taught is a bad thing, and that's the view the third party also has.

Comment: In that case I recommend only allowing access through the Storage API, either the [SDK from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_files) or the one from Google Cloud Storage directly (through a server you control).